# React flux mouse position resets when store emits a change

Tags: scroll, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a page that displays a list of articles. Users will be browsing to the end of the page and click on "load more" to trigger an Action that loads more articles into the list inside the Store. But the react component kind of re-renders the entire page so my viewport resets to the top of the page.

Anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks.

p.s: the architecture is React Flux

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot without more info. What I can imagine, is that in the code updating the new list, you trigger momentarily en empty list (that resets the page scroll), before triggering again with the new list of items. Can you setup a console.log of your store trigger calls to confirm/infirm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [adding a key to each of your components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children). React will re-draw everything unless it knows that certain components haven't changed and so don't need redrawing.

That would be my guess, based on the information provided.

Comment: I previously set the key to be `Math.random().toString()` and no wonder the entire thing is re-rendered again and is very slow.  Thank you!